# How can i calculate the remaining time of the current date with the created date?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to calculate the remaining time until a certain point in the future. I am using `new Date()` to get the current date and i am getting for example:

```
Fri Oct 09 2020 09:59:21 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

How can I calculate the remaining time until this time which is in object:

```
{
   appointment_date: "Tue Oct 20 2020"
   appointment_hour: "08:00 - 09:00"
}
```

I want to show it in months, then weeks, then days, etc. If they are zero, they should be omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`moment.duration()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) for this.

```js
const appointment = {
  appointment_date: "Tue Oct 20 2020",
  appointment_hour: "08:00 - 09:00"
};

const appointmentString = appointment.appointment_date + " " + appointment.appointment_hour.split(' - ')[0];
const difference = moment.duration(
  moment(appointmentString, "ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm").diff(moment()));

const result = [];

const units = [
  "months",
  "weeks",
  "days",
  "hours",
  "minutes",
  "seconds"
];

units.forEach(function(unit) {
  // This is equal to difference.months() > 0, difference.weeks() > 0, etc
  if (difference[unit]() > 0) {
    result.push(difference[unit]() + " " + unit);
  }
});

console.log(result.join(', '));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Ruben for your reply

Answer (score 0):

If you want solution in pure JavaScript try this

```
const appointment = {
  appointment_date: "Tue Oct 20 2020",
  appointment_hour: "08:00 - 09:00"
};

const result = [];
var curr = new Date().getTime();
var appo = new Date(appointment.appointment_date).getTime() + parseInt(appointment.appointment_hour.split(' - ')[0]) *60 *60 *1000;

function dhm(t){
    var cd = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        ch = 60 * 60 * 1000,
        d = Math.floor(t / cd),
        h = Math.floor( (t - d * cd) / ch),
        m = Math.round( (t - d * cd - h * ch) / 60000);
  if( m === 60 ){
    h++;
    m = 0;
  }
  if( h === 24 ){
    d++;
    h = 0;
  }
  return [d, h, m].join(':');
}
console.log(appo - curr)
console.log( dhm( appo - curr ) );
```